# GCM Push Notifications are not recieving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

i am newbie to android.I am implementing Push notifications using GCM.I have done every thing like creating project in console and generating SENDER_ID and API Keys and generating Registration id etc..But Finally Notification is not Recieved.Below is my code

GCMBroadcastReciever.java

```
package com.devpoint.rprtjobs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GCMIntentService.class.getName());
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

GCMIntentService.Java

```
package com.devpoint.rprtjobs;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;

import com.devpoint.rprtgnet.LoadActivity;
import com.devpoint.rprtjobs.R;

public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 112;
    //NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private static int numMessagesTwo = 0;
    //private JSONObject SaveOfferObj;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GCMIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.gcm_msg));
            String FromDeviceId = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.FromDeviceId));
            String ToDeviceId = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.ToDeviceId));
            String GCM_Regid = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.GCM_Regid));
            String UserName = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.Chat_UserName));
            if(ToDeviceId!= null)
            {
                sendNotification(message, UserName , FromDeviceId , ToDeviceId , GCM_Regid);
            }

            GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //PostLogcatErorrs(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message , String UserName, String FromDeviceId , String  ToDeviceId ,  String GCM_Regid) {



        try { 
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(UserName);
            mBuilder.setTicker(UserName + " : New Notification  Received!");

             mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            String[] events = new String[4];
            events[0] = "1) " + FromDeviceId;
            events[1] = "2) " + ToDeviceId;
            events[2] = "3) " + GCM_Regid;
            events[3] = "3) " + message;

            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.sendnoti_title));
            for (String event : events) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(event);
            }
            mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
            mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesTwo);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoadActivity.class);

            resultIntent.putExtra("username",   UserName);
            //resultIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.gcm_push),   getString(R.string.gcm_username));
            resultIntent.putExtra("FromDeviceId",   FromDeviceId);
            resultIntent.putExtra("ToDeviceId",ToDeviceId);
            resultIntent.putExtra("GCM_Regid", GCM_Regid);
            resultIntent.putExtra("UserName", UserName);
            resultIntent.putExtra("PageName", "SplashScreen");
            resultIntent.putExtra("message" ,message);


            resultIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.gcm_push) ,message);       
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            mBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoadActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(notifyID, mBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //PostLogcatErorrs(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my server side code

```
string GoogleAppID = "XXXXXXXXXXX";   //from console
                string SENDER_ID = "XXXXXXXXXX";  //from console
                string regid = MsgObj.GCM_Regid;// Registered from mobile
                WebRequest tRequest;
                tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID)); 
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));


                string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.OpportunityName=" + MsgObj.OpportunityName
                                                                                                             + " &data.OpportunityKeywords=" + MsgObj.OpportunityKeywords
                                                                                                              + "&data.StartDate=" + MsgObj.StartDate
                                                                                                              + "&data.GCM_Regid=" + MsgObj.GCM_Regid
                                 + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regid + "";
                Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();
```

The senderid while registering is same as present in above code.

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.devpoint.rprtjobs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.devpoint.rprtjobs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!--
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

This is my reciever inside Manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.devpoint.rprtjobs" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Please suggest me where the problem is..thank you in advance[image: This is my logcat]

above is my logcat

Comment: Looks like onReceive is being called in GCMBroadcastReceiver, can you confirm that? If so then it may be an issue with your wakelock. Also I'd try using GcmListenerService, which handles all the wakelock stuff for you. Here is an example of how to use it: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart

Comment: @ArthurThompson he is right , onReceive would be called from GCMBroadcastReceiver

Comment: if you want i can give you the wakelocker class code